# Is it correct to say "They crossed 10km"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I came across the following task in my book:

> They carried/crossed 8,120km in the longest windsurfing journey.

Obviously "crossed" is intended to be the correct choice here, but I have never actually heard the verb used in this way. I'm more used to hearing "..crossed a river..", or "..crossed a road.."

Is it really appropriate to use "crossed" with an exact distance, or would "travelled" or "went" be the correct choice here?

Comment: Agreed. **Crossing** kms is not idiomatic. They **covered / travelled** would be the usual verbs.

Answer (score 1):

When speaking of surpassing a record or threshold, you can use the verb **cross**.

> Which communications giant was the first to cross one million and five million customer marks in India? [The Ultimate India Quiz Book by Derek O'Brien]

It's possible the author is thinking of the achievement as *establishing* a record.

But we don't have to resort to conjecture, since we can `cross {a distance}`.

When a measurement in miles or kilometers is presented as the distance, it is usually, but not always, with [another noun](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crossed%20three%20thousand%20miles%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) in a partitive construction:

> ... crossed three thousand miles of ocean
>
> .. crossed 200 miles of tundra